# How to disable the 'Are you sure you want to sign out?' message in Windows scripting?

Tags: windows, scripting

I basically setup command line script for shutdown after some time but don't want to see you're about to sign out message

To not see you're about to sign out message how to disable that message in the windows as if like windows has been automatically shutdown without warning